# Reshaping a vector into a matrix - represent this as a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, operator-theory, computational-algebra

We know that in final dimensional space every linear map can be represented by a matrix. Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^{np \times 1}$ be an $np$-dimensional vector. Then the reshape operation that transforms this vector into a matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is apparently a linear map.

What is the matrix corresponding to this linear map?

$$
f(x) = \texttt{reshape(}x, \texttt{(n, p))}
$$

## My Work

I think that one can find the matrix by seeing what happens to each basis. From what I remember, each column of the matrix represents the action of the linear map on the basis vectors.

Hence
$$
f(e_1) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and in general one has that $f(e_i)$ has all zeros apart from the entry found at row `((i - 1) % n) + 1` and column `(i - 1) ÷ n`. I call the matrix with all zeros except with the entry in the $i$ position as above $E_i$. Then $\{E_1, \ldots, E_{np}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$.

Any vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{np\times 1}$ can be written in terms of the standard basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_{np}\}$
$$
x = c_1e_1 + \ldots + c_{np} e_{np}
$$
for coefficients $c_1, \ldots, c_{np}$. Now this means
$$
f(x) = c_1f(e_1) + \ldots + c_{np} f(e_{np})
$$
In turn, each of the vectors $f(e_j)$ can be written in terms of the basis $\{E_1, \ldots, E_{np}\}$ as
$$
f(e_j) = a_{1j} E_1 + \ldots + a_{npj} E_{np}
$$
Stacking these values into a column gives us the $j^{\text{th}}$ column of the matrix we are looking for. Notice that by definition we have $f(e_j) = E_j$ and so in general $a_{ij} = 0$ unless $i=j$, in which case $a_{ii} = 1$. That is
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1np}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    a_{np1} & \cdots & a_{npnp}
\end{pmatrix} = I_{np}
$$

Comment: The matrix depends on the choice of bases. I suppose there's an obvious choice for the space of columns. If you use for a  basis of the space of $n\times p$ matrices  the matrices with a single non-zero entry $1$, and enumerate these by running down the columns one by one, then the matrix is just the identity matrix.

Comment: And so it's adjoint will be (I think) the canonical vectorisation map.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I tried doing what you suggested and ended up with the matrix above. However surely I made a mistake? The transformation is supposed to be $f:\mathbb{R}^{np\times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ but this matrix is $A\in\mathbb{R}^{np\times np}$ and thus represents a transformation $A:\mathbb{R}^{np \times 1} \to \mathbb{R}^{np\times 1}$.

Comment: All vector spaces of dimension $np$ are isomorphic:.